# How to load a MATLAB file which has 2 arrays, in 1 code of line

Tags: arrays, matlab, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have 1 file with 2 arrays inside it (x and y).
This is the dictionary keys:

```
    dict_keys(['__version__', 'x', '__header__', 'y', '__globals__'])
```

These are the instructions I write to call my arrays without the dict_keys:

```
    x=sio.loadmat('C:/Users/rocio/Documents/Python Scripts/SLEEP/SLEEP_F4/FeaturesAll/AWA_FeaturesAll.mat')['x']
    y=sio.loadmat('C:/Users/rocio/Documents/Python Scripts/SLEEP/SLEEP_F4/FeaturesAll/AWA_FeaturesAll.mat')['y']
```

Is there a way to do this with only one line of code?

I have tried this so far without success:

```
    x_y=sio.loadmat('C:/Users/rocio/Documents/Python Scripts/SLEEP/SLEEP_F4/FeaturesAll/AWA_FeaturesAll.mat')['x']['y']


    x_y=(sio.loadmat('C:/Users/rocio/Documents/Python Scripts/SLEEP/SLEEP_F4/FeaturesAll/AWA_FeaturesAll.mat')(['x','y']))

    x_y=sio.loadmat('C:/Users/rocio/Documents/Python Scripts/SLEEP/SLEEP_F4/FeaturesAll/AWA_FeaturesAll.mat')(['x']['y'])

    x_y=(sio.loadmat('C:/Users/rocio/Documents/Python Scripts/SLEEP/SLEEP_F4/FeaturesAll/AWA_FeaturesAll.mat')(['x']['y']))
```

Comment: Don't do this, but `x, y = (lambda d: (d['x'], d['y']))(sio.loadmat(...))`

Comment: Which can be better spelt `x, y = operator.itemgetter('x', 'y')(sio.loadmat(...))`

Answer (score 3):

Is it really that important to do this in *one line*?  It makes sense to want just one call to `loadmat()`, but insisting on one line seems unnecessary.  This looks pretty straightforward:

```
features = sio.loadmat('C:/Users/rocio/Documents/Python Scripts/SLEEP/SLEEP_F4/FeaturesAll/AWA_FeaturesAll.mat')
x = features['x']
y = features['y']
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know it could be done that way! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on a one-liner, this will work:

```
x_y = {k:v for (k, v) in sio.loadmat('C:/Users/rocio/Documents/Python Scripts/SLEEP/SLEEP_F4/FeaturesAll/AWA_FeaturesAll.mat').items() if k in {'x', 'y'}}
```

<sup>(Requires Python 3.x or 2.7)</sup>

It runs `loadmat` only once, then loops over its contents using a dict comprehension, to select only those `(k, v)` pairs where `k` (the key) is contained in the set `{'x', 'y'}`.

It doesn't matter that it is a MAT-file.  It works for any object where the `.items()` method behaves like `dict.items()`.

If you are still using Python 2.7, you may want to replace `.items()` by `.iteritems()` for better performance.

Comment: But is it possible to remove the names of the arrays? {'y': array([[  1.],
       ..., 
       [ 37.]]), 'x': array([[  4.56510305e+00,   4.53280275e+00, ..., Otherwise to use the arrays I still need to use 2 commands: x1 = x_y['x'] and x2 = x_y['y']

Comment: @Aizzaac Probably, do you mean that it contains a dict in a dict?  You may have to replace `[k]` by `[k][k]` then, or even `[k][k].squeeze()` if you want to get rid of the atleast_2d that every Matlab object is.  It's been a while since I tried to read MAT-files in Python and I don't have any Matlab license handy right now to test what they look like again.